# Runtime c++ struct append

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I am developing a library of 3D graphics and now I am working on a "module" focused on DirectX 11.

DirectX 11 uses constant buffers to send information to Shaders. There is a more detailed explanation of their use [here](https://bell0bytes.eu/shader-data/).

Basically, I need a struct in C++ that matches a constant buffer inside the shader, for example:

```
// C++ struct
struct dataToShader{
    float r;
    float g;
    float b;
};

// HLSL Constant Buffers
cbuffer ConstantColourBuffer
{
    float red;
    float green;
    float blue;
};
```

When I wrote structures manually, there was no problem. But I would like to make a loader for my shaders. This loader should fetch the shader properties and HLSL code from a file.

How can I append information to my structure in C++ at runtime?

Comment: The types that exist in C++ source code no longer exist in the compiled code. This is the nature of C++. So the answer to your question is that it is not possible to manipulate C++ types at run time. BTW this is usually called *reflection* and some languages have better support for it than C++.

Comment: You could write a *parser* for your file, and dynamically allocate memory with a data structure such as `std::vector<float>`, of which the method `reserve(...)` should be invoked properly, according to the count of `float` the *parser* encountered in the file.